# Do we have to create a tree all the nodes of which have 3 children?

Tags: algorithm, tree, heap, huffman-code

Steps to build Huffman Tree
Input is array of unique characters along with their frequency of occurrences and output is Huffman Tree.

1. Create a leaf node for each unique character and build a min heap of all leaf nodes (Min Heap is used as a priority queue. The value of frequency field is used to compare two nodes in min heap. Initially, the least frequent character is at root)
2. Extract two nodes with the minimum frequency from the min heap.
3. Create a new internal node with frequency equal to the sum of the two nodes frequencies. Make the first extracted node as its left child and the other extracted node as its right child. Add this node to the min heap.
4. Repeat steps#2 and #3 until the heap contains only one node. The remaining node is the root node and the tree is complete.

At a heap, a node can have at most 2 children, right?

So if we would like to generalize the Huffman algorithm for coded words in ternary system (i.e. coded words using the symbols 0 , 1 and 2 ) what could we do? Do we have to create a tree all the nodes of which have 3 children?

**EDIT**:

I think that it would be as follows.

Steps to build Huffman Tree
Input is array of unique characters along with their frequency of occurrences and output is Huffman Tree.

1. Create a leaf node for each unique character and build a min heap of all leaf nodes
2. Extract three nodes with the minimum frequency from the min heap.
3. Create a new internal node with frequency equal to the sum of the three nodes frequencies. Make the first extracted node as its left child, the second extracted node as its middle child and the third extracted node as its right child. Add this node to the min heap.
4. Repeat steps#2 and #3 until the heap contains only one node. The remaining node is the root node and the tree is complete.

How can we prove that the algorithm yields optimal ternary codes?

**EDIT 2**: Suppose that we have the frequencies 5,9,12,13,16,45.

Their number is even, so we add a dummy node with frequency 0. Do we put this at the end of the array? So, will it be as follows?

[image]

Then will we have the following heap?

[image]

Then:

[image]

Then:

[image]

Or have I understood it wrong?

Comment: The quest for a proof might do better over at [Computer Science beta](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 7):

Yes! you have to create all nodes with 3 children. Why 3? you can also have `n-ary huffman coding` using nodes with n child. The tree will look something like this-(for n=3)

```
    *
  / | \
 *  *  *
   /|\
  * * *
```

### Huffman Algorithm for Ternary Codewords

I am giving the algorithms for easy reference.

```
HUFFMAN_TERNARY(C)
{
   IF |C|=EVEN 
   THEN ADD DUMMY CHARACTER Z WITH FREQUENCY 0.

   N=|C|
   Q=C;  //WE ARE BASICALLY HEAPIFYING THE CHARACTERS

   FOR I=1 TO floor(N/2)
   {
     ALLOCATE NEW_NODE;
     LEFT[NEW_NODE]= U= EXTRACT_MIN(Q)
     MID[NEW_NODE] = V= EXTRACT_MIN(Q)
     RIGHT[NEW_NODE]=W= EXTRACT_MIN(Q)
     F[NEW_NODE]=F[U]+F[V]+F[W];
     INSERT(Q,NEW_NODE);
   }
   RETURN EXTRACT_MIN(Q);
  } //END-OF-ALGO
```

> `Why are we adding extra nodes?` To make the number of nodes odd.(Why?) Because we want to get out of the for loop with just **one node** in Q.

---

> `Why floor(N/2)?`
>   At first we take 3 nodes. Then replace with it 1 node.There are N-2 nodes.
>   After that we always take 3 nodes (if not available 1 node,it is never possible to get 2 nodes because of the dummy node) and replace with 1. In each iteration we are reducing it by 2 nodes. So that's why we are using the term `floor(N/2)`.

Check it yourself in paper using some sample character set. You will understand.

### CORRECTNESS

I am taking here reference from "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen, Rivest.

Proof: The step by step mathematical proof is too long to post here but it is quite similar to the proof given in the book.

#### Idea

> Any `optimal tree` has the lowest three frequencies at the lowest level.(We have to prove this).(using contradiction) Suppose it is not the case then we could switch a leaf with a higher frequency from the lowest level with one of the lowest three leaves and obtain a lower average length. Without any loss of generality, we can assume that all the three lowest frequencies are the children of the same node. if they are at the same level, the average length does not change irrespective of where the frequencies are). They only differ in the last digit of their codeword (one will be 0,1 or 2).
>
> Again as the binary codewords we have to contract the three nodes and make a new character out of it having `frequency=total of three node's(character's) frequencies`. Like binary Huffman codes, we see that the cost of the optimal tree is the sum of the tree
>   with the three symbols `contracted` and the `eliminated sub-tree` which had the nodes before contraction. Since it has been proved that the sub-tree has
>   to be present in the final optimal tree, we can optimize on the tree with the contracted newly created node.

### Example

- Suppose the character set contains frequencies 5,9,12,13,16,45.
- Now N=6-> even. So add dummy character with freq=0
- N=7 now and freq in C are 0,5,9,12,13,16,45
- Now using `min priority queue` get 3 values. `0` then `5` then `9`.
- Add them insert new char with freq=0+9+5 in priority queue. This way continue.

The tree will be like this

```
         100
        / | \
       /  |  \
      /   |   \
     39   16  45  step-3
   /  | \
  14  12 13  step-2
/ | \  
0 5 9   step-1
```

### Finally Prove it

I will now go to straight forward mimic of the proof of Cormen.

**Lemma 1.** Let C be an alphabet in which each character d belonging to C has frequency c.freq. Let
x ,y and z be three characters in C having the lowest frequencies. Then there exists
an optimal prefix code for C in which the codewords for x ,y and z have the same
length and differ only in the last bit.

---

**Proof**:

#### Idea

- First consider any tree T generating arbitrary optimal prefix code.
- Then we will modify it to make a tree representing another optimal prefix such that the characters x,y,z appears as sibling nodes at the maximum depth.
- If we can construct such a tree then the codewords for x,y and z will have the same length and differ only in the last bit.

Proof--

- Let a,b,c be three characters that are sibling leaves of maximum depth in T .

> - Without loss of generality, we assume that `a.freq < b:freq < c.freq` and `x.freq < y.freq < z.freq`.
>     Since x.freq and y.freq and z.freq are the 3 lowest leaf frequencies, in order (`means there are no frequencies between them`) and a.freq
>     , b.freq and c.freq are two arbitrary frequencies, in order, `we have x.freq < a:freq and
>     y.freq < b.freq and z.freq< c.freq.`

---

> In the remainder of the proof we can have x.freq=a.freq or y.freq=b.freq or z.freq=c.freq. 
>     But if x.freq=b.freq or x.freq=c.freq
>     or   y.freq=c.freq 
>     then all of them are same. WHY??
>     Let's see. Suppose `x!=y,y!=z,x!=z` but z=c and `x<y<z` in order and aa<b<c.
>     Also `x!=a. --> x<a`
>          `y!=b. --> y<b`
>          `z!=c. --> z<c` but `z=c` is given. This contradicts our assumption. (Thus proves).
>    The lemma would be trivially true. Thus we will assume
>    x!=b and x!=c.
>
> ```
>  T1
>
>      *                       |
>    / | \                     |
>   *  *  x                    +---d(x)
> / | \                        |
> y *  z                           +---d(y) or d(z)
>  /|\                         |
> a b c                        +---d(a) or d(b) or d(c) actually d(a)=d(b)=d(c)
>
> T2
>      *              
>    / | \
>   *  *  a
> / | \
> y *  z
>  /|\
> x b c               
>
> T3
>
>      *              
>    / | \
>   *  *  x
> / | \
> b *  z
>  /|\
> x y c
>
> T4
>      *              
>    / | \
>   *  *  a
> / | \
> b *  c
>  /|\
> x y z
>
>
> In case of T1 costt1= x.freq*d(x)+ cost_of_other_nodes + y.freq*d(y) + z.freq*d(z) + d(a)*a.freq + b.freq*d(b) + c.freq*d(c)
> In case of T2 costt2= x.freq*d(a)+ cost_of_other_nodes + y.freq*d(y) + z.freq*d(z) + d(x)*a.freq + b.freq*d(b) + c.freq*d(c)
>        costt1-costt2= x.freq*[d(x)-d(a)]+0             +    0        +     0       + a.freq[d(a)-d(x)]+0       +    0
>                     = (a.freq-x.freq)*(d(a)-d(x))
>                     >= 0      
> So costt1>=costt2.                    --->(1)
> ```

```
Similarly we can show costt2 >= costt3--->(2)

And                   costt3 >= costt4--->(3)

From (1),(2) and (3) we get 

costt1>=costt4.-->(4)

But T1 is optimal.

So costt1<=costt4 -->(5)

From (4) and (5) we get costt1=costt2.

SO, T4 is an optimal tree in which x,y,and z appears as sibling leaves at maximum depth, from which the lemma follows.
```

---

**Lemma-2**

> Let C be a given alphabet with frequency c.freq defined for each character c belonging to C.
>   Let x , y, z be three characters in C with minimum frequency. Let C1 be the
>   alphabet C with the characters x and y removed and a new character z1 added,
>   so that `C1 = C - {x,y,z} union {z1}`. Define f for C1 as for C, except that
>   `z1.freq=x.freq+y.freq+z.freq`. Let T1 be any tree representing an optimal prefix code
>   for the alphabet C1. Then the tree T , obtained from T1 by replacing the leaf node
>   for z with an internal node having x , y and z as children, represents an optimal prefix
>   code for the alphabet C.

Proof.:

Look we are making a transition from T1-> T.
So we must find a way to express the T i.e, costt in terms of costt1.

```
     *                            *              
   / | \                        / | \
  *  *  *                      *  *  *
/ | \                           / | \
* *  *        ---->             * z1 *
 /|\                            
x y z
```

For c belonging to (C-{x,y,z}), dT(c)=dT1(c). [depth corresponding to T and T1 tree]

Hence `c.freq*dT(c)=c.freq*dT1(c)`.

Since `dT(x)=dT(y)=dT(z)=dT1(z1)+1`

```
So we have `x.freq*dT(x)+y.freq*dT(y)+z.freq*dT(z)=(x.freq+y.freq+z.freq)(dT1(z)+1)`
                                                  = `z1.freq*dT1(z1)+x.freq+y.freq+z.freq`
Adding both side the cost of other nodes which is same in both T and T1.
x.freq*dT(x)+y.freq*dT(y)+z.freq*dT(z)+cost_of_other_nodes= z1.freq*dT1(z1)+x.freq+y.freq+z.freq+cost_of_other_nodes

So costt=costt1+x.freq+y.freq+z.freq
or equivalently

  costt1=costt-x.freq-y.freq-z.freq ---->(1)
```

Now we prove the lemma by contradiction.

We now prove the lemma by contradiction. Suppose that T does not represent
an optimal prefix code for C. Then there exists an optimal tree T2 such that
`costt2 < costt`. Without loss of generality (by Lemma 1), T2 has x and y and z as
siblings. 
Let T3 be the tree T2 with the common parent of x and y and z replaced by a
leaf z1 with frequency `z1.freq=x.freq+y.freq+z.freq` Then

```
costt3 = costt2-x.freq-y.freq-z.freq
       <  costt-x.freq-y.freq-z.freq
       =  costt1  (From 1)
```

yielding a contradiction to the assumption that T1 represents an optimal prefix code
for C1. Thus, T must represent an optimal prefix code for the alphabet C.

```
-Proved.
```

Procedure HUFFMAN produces an optimal prefix code.
Proof: Immediate from Lemmas 1 and 2.

**NOTE**.: Terminologies are from **Introduction to Algorithms 3rd edition Cormen Rivest**

Comment: Nice... I edited my post and added an algorithm.. Could you take a look at it? Could you maybe also tell me  how we could show that the algorithm yields optimal ternary codes?

Comment: @evinda.: I am modifying my answer. Sorry for late response.

Comment: I haven't understood why at the algorithm, if |C|=EVEN 
   we add a dummy character z with frequence 0. Could you explain it to me? Also, we at the condition for the for-loop do we take I from 1 to N/2 ?

Comment: I have edited my initial post,by  adding an example in order to see if I have understood it ..  Could you tell me if this is right?

Comment: I haven't understood the idea of the proof... Could you explain it further to me?

Comment: @evinda.:Have you understood the post? If there is anything that seems problematic about this post you can ask me. Be sure to read section of `huffman tree`from the book of `CLRS` atleast twice. Then just read each of part of my proof. Don't read all at once rather read step by step and move to next portion only if you have understood the current one.

Comment: @coderredoc this is a masterful answer, thank you for that. It was stated to me that in the real world, we would not generalize to ternary codewords. So this seems to be more of a theoretical practice. Any idea why with Huffman codes, it's impractical in the real world? Is it because of the dummies?

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if I don't add a dummy node, and when less than three nodes are left at last, just merge the remaining. 

for example: 5 9 12 13 16 45

step1: (5 9 12) 13 16 45

Step2: (26 13 16) 45

Step 3: 55 45

Now just two nodes are left so merge both.

Step4: 100.

Will this idea work? Is it optimal? If no how to prove it?